# How to automatically switch between apps and/or websites on Android?

Tags: applications

So I'd like to turn a tablet into a calendar, alarm, weather display, and task organizer that shuffles between these every five minutes when not being used. It will be mounted on a wall or next to my dual monitors.

Most likely going to use google calendar, android native clock, a generic weather app, and a custom app or web app respectively.

Any good ways to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly a job for **[Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tasker/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** (see also: [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker), [automation](/questions/tagged/automation)). You could create a profile being active permanently, and assign it a task running in a loop. An example could look like:

> - **Condition:** WiFi connected (your WiFi SSID) <sup>have it running all the time while connected to your WiFi</sup>
> - **Task:**
>
>   ```
>   FOREACH %item 0:3
>     LAUNCH APP (Google Calendar) IF %item = 0
>     LAUNCH APP (Clock) IF %item = 1
>     LAUNCH APP (Weather) IF %item = 2
>     WAIT 5 min
>   ```

The "LAUNCH APP" action lets you select the app to launch. So the loop would count from 0 to 3, launch the corresponding app, then wait 5 minutes (i.e. the app stays in foreground for those 5 minutes). Once #3 has been processed, the task would quit – but should immediately be re-launched, as the condition is still met.

I've not tested this specific configuration, so above is "plain theory" – but should get you started. You can consult the [Tasker User Guide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/) for available commands etc, but *Tasker* also offers a context-sensitive built-in help. Get yourself a [7-day Trial](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html) first if you want to test it first, it's available on the project site.